# How to generate numbers for showing sequence in SSRS also it should get rearrenge when any field inbetween is missing

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

I am facing problem in SSRS report for showing sequense numbers as given in image.

when I searched for this issue I got solution as -- RowNumber("DataSetName")
but problem with this is, it generate numbers like 1,2,3..., but I want these numbers in following forms- 1.1, 1.2 or 1.1.1, 1.2.1.

And another problem for me is above function will work if I am having multiple rows in dataset and that dataset is bind with table to show its data, but In my case I am getting all data in single row and out of that I am showing values in textbox using expressions and if that value is empty I am hiding that textbox.
so I am not getting any solution to show sequence number in textbox along with text and how I can rearrenge that numbers if my inbetween textbox is hidden because of no data.

Please provide me solution for above probem.

Image for reference - [image]

Example of data is :

[image]

From above table values from "Subheading1" And "Subheading2" will show inside "Heading first" and "Subheading3" And "Subheading4" will show inside "Heading second".

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate row numbers as strings as follows:

```
=RowNumber("HEADING") & "." & RowNumber("SUBHEADING")
```

To ensure numbers are consecutive remove the relevant rows in the source dataset instead of hiding them in the tablix.

Comment: I cannot use RowNumber because my data is comming in single row.

Comment: Please can you add an example of your data to the question?

Comment: I have updated my qustion with example of data, please check.